# Having extra white space at the left and right side of my SVG after exporting from Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I made a 1920x1080 sized SVG using Illustrator. After exporting to SVG, there are spaces at the left and right side of the SVG. I had tried a few times and make sure than i fit the artwork to the artboard and export with use artboard checked.
This is the view from Illustrator:
[image: Illustration View]

This is the view from a browser:
[image: Web View]

The question is how do i remove the white space and make it fit to my browser's view?

Comment: Just a *guess* -- Raster effects creating shadows? You may need a clipping mask the size the of the artboard to work around the extra space the effects create.

Comment: Looks like a conflation artefact to me.